# Metodo INSERT com erro PHP OO usando SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

Essa é minha classe **conexão** no banco de dados

```
class Conection {
    private $_host = 'ALISON\MSSQLSERVER2';
    private $_user = 'banco';
    private $_pass = '123456';
    private $_database = 'aulateste';
    private $_con;
    function __construct(){
        $this->conecta();
    }
    public function conecta() {
        $_coninfo = array("Database" =>$this->_database, "UID" =>$this->_user, "PWD" =>$this->_pass);
        $_con = sqlsrv_connect($this->_host, $_coninfo);

        if($_con) {
            echo "Conexão estabelecida";
        }else{
            echo "Conexão não estabelecida";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é o meu método de **inserir** :

```
public function cadastrar_autor($Id_autor,$Nome_autor, $Sobrenome_autor){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_autor VALUES($this->Id_autor,$this->Nome_autor,$this->Sobrenome_autor)";
        $sql_inserir = sqlsrv_query($sql,$this->conect);                                   
        if($sql_inserir > 0){
            echo"Cadastrou";
        }else{
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
```

**Erro**

> An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query

Comment: Qual e descrição da mensagem de erro ? você precisa editar sua pergunta nos diga mais informações sobre seu problema , em que momento este erro ocorre durante a execução do cadastrar_autor() ?

Comment: Tem outros jeitos de fazer mas valores literais devem estar entre aspas simples.

Comment: Qual erro aparece? de sintaxe inválida pela falta de aspas simples nos valores? por algum valor no campo identity?

Comment: @stringNome  An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query esse é o seguinte erro, fiz estruturado neste mesmo segmento e deu certo, porém OO da esse erro, sou novo em SQL SERVER não sabia que um banco de dados diferente fazia uma grande diferença no codigo, sou oriundo do Mysql

Comment: @rray esse é o erro  An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query a conexao existe mas ta com o valor de NULL

Comment: O correto é `sqlsrv_query($this->conect, $sql); `

Comment: já fiz isso, esse é o erro quando altero, sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in

Comment: Coloca o código que chama o `inserir()` vc não armazena sua conexão em lugar nenhum.

Comment: não entendi o que você quis dizer

Comment: Em algum lugar vc chama `cadastrar_autor()` coloca esse código tbm

Comment: sim no meu view chamo o método cadastrar a classe do banco e distinta da classe do autor

Comment: vc pode colocar esse código na pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Pelos fragmentos de código da pergunta e pelos comentários o problema principal é que a conexão não é feita ou passada corretamente para a classe `Autor` que realiza o insert.

Outros problemas são:

- A classe `Conection` não armazena ou devolve a conexão.
- A ordem dos argumentos de `sqlsrv_query()` está invertida;
- O código está vulneravel a sql injection

Comment: O objeto trás as configurações da conexão, porém ficam dando esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

**Seu código precisa de algumas observações:**

1) quando se cadastra algo no banco de dados, é recomendável manter uma chave `auto_increment`, desta maneira não há necessidade de incrementar a id do autor.

2) quando se passa parâmetros para inserir dados no BD, você deve colocar as aspas, só para valores (booleano, numérico, now(), null, etc... que não há necessidade de aspas). Porém, passar os valores sem um tratamento antes, é uma forma insegura de cadastrar dados no banco, pois dá espaço para [**SQL Injection**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), você pode usar tratamentos como: `preg_split()`, `preg_replace('/sua_expressao_regular/','',$data)`, e outras "cositas más". Eu recomendo o uso de PDO neste caso, se está trabalhando com SQL Server, ele contém placeholders que evitam esse tipo de entrada de dados e risco [**consulte o PDO aqui**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-dblib.php).

Resolvendo a questão, se você está usando `$this`, que pertence a sua classe em questão não faz sentido passar os dados por parâmetro. Entendo que você já deve ter atribuído por um método `set`, os dados "nome" e "sobrenome", já que são atributos da sua classe, mas eu daria uma melhorada nisso, não usando Letra maiúscula no começo de atributos e seguiria o padrão de normalização das [**PSRs**](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

```
private $Nome_autor;
private $Sobrenome_autor;

public function setNome($string)
{
    $this->Nome_autor = $string;
}

public function setSobrenome($string)
{
    $this->Sobrenome_autor = $string;
}
public function cadastrar_autor()
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_autor (nome, sobrenome) VALUES ('$this->Nome_autor','$this->Sobrenome_autor')";
   $sql_inserir = sqlsrv_query($sql,$this->conect);                                   
    if ($sql_inserir > 0) {
       echo"Cadastrou";
    } else {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```

Caso contrário, o correto seria fazer isso:

```
public function cadastrar_autor($nome, $sobrenome)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_autor (nome, sobrenome) VALUES('$nome','$sobrenome')";
    $sql_inserir = sqlsrv_query($sql,$this->conect);                                   
    if ($sql_inserir > 0) {
       echo"Cadastrou";
    } else {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```

E também separaria a classe de conexão da sua entidade "Autor".

Answer (score -3):

```
public function insert($sql){
    $return = sqlsrv_query($this->_con,$sql);
    if($return > 0){
        echo"deu";
    }else{
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}

public function cadastrar_autor($Id_autor,$Nome_autor, $Sobrenome_autor){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_autor(Id_autor,Nome_autor,Sobrenome_autor)VALUES('$Id_autor','$Nome_autor','$Sobrenome_autor')";
  $this->conect->insert($sql);
}
```

Essa foi a única solução que consegui, criei um método inserir na classe de Conexão,e chamo ele na classe Autor com o metodo cadastrar_autor. Não fico muito feliz porque acredito que a classe conexão seja apenas para conexão, e não adicionar outros métodos. Se alguém souber outra forma que possa me passar, agradeço.

Comment: esse é o meu método de inserir, por favor sou novo aqui, não me dê negativo, so quero ajuda, se for negativar nem precisa olhar

Comment: Você pode remover este item afinal não e uma resposta correto ? você deve clicar em editar e fazer as edições necessárias em sua pergunta.

Comment: @stringNome sou novo nesse negocio só quero um help nada mais

Comment: Sim existe outra forma de fazer isso!